# Newbie: CodeIgniter, JQuery & Ajax - Not returning/displaying values

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm attempting to following the tutorials found here: http://www.ifadey.com/2010/06/crud-using-jquery-and-codeigniter/  My code is updated to accomodate for CI and JQ updates.  But when attempting to load data from my db and display it in my view, nothing happens/is displayed. All links to javascript (JQ) code work and everything is running locally using MAMP. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

My code is as follows,

Model:

```
<?php
class mUsers extends CI_Model { 
    public function getAll() {

        //get all records from users table
         $this->db->_compile_select();  
        $query=$this->db->get('users')->result();        
        //OR $query = $this->db->get('users');
        echo $this->db->last_query();

        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return array();
        }

    } //end getAll

} //end class
?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
class Site extends CI_Controller{
   public function index(){
       $this->load->model('mUsers');       
       $this->load->view('home');
   }

 public function read(){
     header('Content-Type: application/json',true); 
     echo json_encode($this->mUsers->getAll());

 }

}

?>
```

View:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

        <base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" />


</head>
<body>


    <div id="tabs">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#read">Read</a></li>
        <li><a href="#create">Create</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="read">
        <table id="records"></table>
    </div>

    <div id="create">Create form goes here...</div>

</div> <!-- end tabs -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="readTemplate">
        <tr>
            <td>${id}</td>
            <td>${name}</td>
            <td>${email}</td>
        </tr>
    </script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/all.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Ajax call should contain .tmpl, not .render:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'index.php/site/read',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( response ) {
             $( '#readTemplate' ).tmpl( response ).appendTo( "#records" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't autoload mUsers model so Site->read() method won't output any data from database as it doesn't know the model's getAll() method.

You should load the model in every method that needs it or rather in the constructor since probably most methods of the Site controller will use it:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mUsers');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

    function read()
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json',true); 
        echo json_encode($this->mUsers->getAll());
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but still no luck.  Is there a suggested way to debug the code?  Thanks!

Comment: If I edit my controller function to include $this->load->model('mUsers'); prior to the echo json_encode, and then I paste the URL in directly to access the controller (http://127.0.0.1/CI/index.php/site/read) I finally get data returned as: [{"id":"1","name":"Fawad Hassan","email":"fawad@test.com"},{"id":"2","name":"Bill Gates","email":"bill@test.com"},{"id":"3","name":"Steve Jobs","email":"steve@test.com"},{"id":"4","name":"Naveed Ahmad","email":"naveed@test.com"},{"id":"5","name":"Mr Zee","email":"zee@test.com"}], but still cannot get it to load into the display

Comment: And where is your ajax call to get that data? In your code there is no such javascript.

Comment: ajax call is in the file all.js located at the bottom of my view.  I've isolated the issue to ".render" in the following: $( '#readTemplate' ).render( response ).appendTo( "#records" );  but when I then add a jquery render function, I now get ".replace is not a function"...replace is found in the render function

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent tutorial on templating on nettuts.

Try changing your template script to this

```
<script id="readTemplates" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
```

Im not really up on templates but dont you need to define $Id $name $email? This is an example from one of my templates getting stuff from twitter. This info can be received from firebug

```
 <script id="tweets" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
     <li class="display">
        <img src="${imgSource}" alt="${userName}" />
        <h4> ${username} </h4>
        <p> ${tweet} </p>
        <hr />

     </li>
  </script>

  <ul id="twitters"></ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        url : 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=my id',

        success : function(tweets) {   

           var twitter = $.map(tweets.results, function(obj, index) {
              return {
                 username : obj.from_user,
                 tweet : obj.text,
                 imgSource : obj.profile_image_url,
                 geo : obj.geo
              };
           });

           $('#tweets').tmpl(twitter).appendTo('#twitters');
        }
  });

  </script>
```

Note that the return values I use are defined at the bottom of the script.  This may not solve your problem but give you a better idea how templating works